# Getting a list of files in a directory for uploading in ngCordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm building a mobile app in Ionic. As part of the app I would like to get a list of all files in a given directory and then use something like the [Cordova File Transfer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) plugin to upload them to a remote site.

I've been working with the [Cordova File Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) to create files on an android mobile device. And check if a specific file exists in a specific location. But there doesn't seem to be a way of listing all files in a directory. The page linked to doesn't list any such methods.

Has anyone previously coded what I'm trying to do, who can advise on the best way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found. For future reference, the `ngCordova` file plugin source has a `listDir` function that has been commented out in the version I'm using (0.1.23-alpha). Apparently, however, that function can be used according to [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/why-was-ngcordova-file-plugin-listdir-function-removed/29003) post on the Ionic forum. The work-around for me was to uncomment the function and add `{create: false}` as an option parameter to the `FileSystem.getDirectory` call (line 2911). Tested on an android device and it seems to work.